# PHP Files are not moving from /tmp

Tags: php, apache, laravel

In my link, the images are not displaying because they are not moving from `/tmp` to the specified dir. The php script pointers are correct and have verified that with `file_exists()`. Also the script to process the images was working correctly on my machine.

I have checked all php.ini settings defined in php.net; *file_uploads, upload_max_filesize, upload_tmp_dir, post_max_size and max_input_time*.

I have also checked file modes for `/tmp`, and the upload directories. All are verified to be 777.

I have checked php error_log and have no errors.

Any ideas appreciated, I have been at it for 6 hours with no progress...

**Server / App Details:**
CentOS7, Apache 2.4.6, PHP 5.4.16, Laravel 4.2

Code Responsible for This:

```
public function createTN($image) {
    # Load Zebra Image Library
    require_once public_path().'/uploads/Zebra_Image.php';
    $destinationPath = public_path().'/uploads/thumbnails/';

    $tn = new Zebra_Image();
    $tn->source_path = $image->getRealPath();
    $tn->target_path = $destinationPath.$this->name.'.jpg';
    $tn->jpeg_quality = 60;
    $tn->preserve_aspect_ratio = true;
    $tn->enlarge_smaller_images = true;
    $tn->resize(100, 100, ZEBRA_IMAGE_CROP_CENTER);
}
```

*PS: The `public_path()` is correct*

Comment: give apache ownsership of the folder `chown apache:apache ./foldername`

Comment: Just did that to `./uploads` and verified the change with `getfacl ./uploads`...the owner is now apache but still no success

Comment: The image urls in the page you linked to point to /uploads/smalls/some.jpg whereas your code seems to store in /uploads/thumbnails/some.jpg.
Changing the url didn't help, but at least that seems to be wrong. The Laravel routing error would let me check rewrite rules as well.

Comment: @ChristianM hey I really appreciate your insight. My question has been semi answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28920545/images-not-showing-on-my-site it looks like I needed **libgd**

Comment: @Rafael no problem, indeed Zebra_Image needs GD enabled. I just didn't expect a server without it ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Make sure libgd is installed!

http://libgd.github.io/

http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php

### CentOS users

1. `yum install gd gd-devel php-gd`
2. Restart http server (in my case apache).