# Images not showing on my site

Tags: php, apache, laravel

I hate to ask this kind of question. But the images arent showing on my web server like they were on my local system.

PHP info http://www.classifiedtestbed.com/test.php

Example of missing images: http://www.classifiedtestbed.com/advertisements/2

My script is correct but I am thinking this could a apache or php problem please look at my phpinfo() and tell me if you see anything wrong.

The images should be processing from my tmp dir and moving to my uploads dir but that never happens...I get not errors in php_errors and have checked httd/error_log

Any suggestions would be super appreciated, thank you!

```
public function createTN($image) {
    # Load Zebra Image Library
    require_once public_path().'/uploads/Zebra_Image.php';
    $destinationPath = public_path().'/uploads/thumbnails/';

    $tn = new Zebra_Image();
    $tn->source_path = $image->getRealPath();
    $tn->target_path = $destinationPath.$this->name.'.jpg';
    $tn->jpeg_quality = 60;
    $tn->preserve_aspect_ratio = true;
    $tn->enlarge_smaller_images = true;
    $tn->resize(100, 100, ZEBRA_IMAGE_CROP_CENTER);
}
```

*ps: file modes have been changed to 777 already*

[PHP Files are not moving from /tmp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28912684/php-files-are-not-moving-from-tmp?noredirect=1#comment46083907_28912684)

### New code

```
public function createTN($image) {
    # Load Zebra Image Library
    require_once public_path().'/uploads/Zebra_Image.php';
    $destinationPath = public_path().'/uploads/thumbnails/';

    $tn = new Zebra_Image();
    $tn->source_path = $image->getRealPath();
    $tn->target_path = $destinationPath.$this->name.'.jpg';
    $tn->jpeg_quality = 60;
    $tn->preserve_aspect_ratio = true;
    $tn->enlarge_smaller_images = true;

    if (!$tn->resize(100, 100, ZEBRA_IMAGE_CROP_CENTER)) echo 'Error: ' . $tn->error;
    echo 'Is file: ' . is_file($tn->source_path);
    exit;
    /*$tn->resize(100, 100, ZEBRA_IMAGE_CROP_CENTER);*/
}
```

Output: `Error: 7Is file: 1`

Comment: Have you made sure your image paths are correct?  Looks like Laravel is throwing a "Not found" exception.  Double check the root of your path references.

Comment: Have you checked laravels logs in `storage/logs` for errors?

Comment: I'm not an expert of Laravel, but shouldn't you have to store the images in the public path to be viewed?

Comment: Hey guys I know you are telling me to check my paths but understand that the css documents would not have been loaded have my public path been incorrect.

Comment: @lukasgeiter I just checked storage/logs/laravel.log and found no errors

Comment: Maybe your local test system is Windows, and your server has Linux. Linux has case-sensitive filenames, and this affects how the webserver handles them too. The files are clearly not found, as you can see when you try to load a single image: http://www.classifiedtestbed.com/uploads/smalls/hgt2IgGlRD7euxk4.jpg

Comment: @GolezTrol hmm good thinking I will double check everything again.

Comment: @GolezTrol they are not found because they are not processing from the tmp dir to that specified dir I have included my image processing code so you can see that I am in fact saving them there but it's not happening :(

Comment: When I try to click on your links, avast Internet security says that there's a treat and blocks it

Comment: To see what's exactly wrong, you can test it like so `if (!$tn->resize(100, 100, ZEBRA_IMAGE_CROP_CENTER)) {  echo $tn->error; }`. Also test and make sure that `is_file($tn->source_path)` returns `true`

Comment: @bad_boy hey I did what you said please check my new code

Comment: Looks like you have 7 error here, scroll down a bit: https://github.com/stefangabos/Zebra_Image/

Comment: and 1 is the result of `is_file()` (which means true), so its irrelevant

Comment: Man you are awesome @bad_boy checked the docs and says gd library is not installed....now at least I have a place to look. I will look into this.

Comment: Looks like I need to install this http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php

Comment: @bad_boy please formulate and answer with all of this information so I can appropriately credit you for helping me. Thank you man, I really can't thank you enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When somethings fails down, you can simply debug things step by step to see if they produce expected result. So in your case, that was a method `$tn->resize(100, 100, ZEBRA_IMAGE_CROP_CENTER);` which is meant to resize an image and save it.

From zebra's source code we have:

```
 *  @return boolean                         Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on error.
 *
 *                                          If FALSE is returned, check the {@link error} property to see what went
 *                                          wrong
 */
public function resize($width = 0, $height = 0, $method = ZEBRA_IMAGE_CROP_CENTER, $background_color = '#FFFFFF')
```

So obliviously, to find out what went wrong, you could simply test it like this:

```
if ( ! $tm->resize(..) ){
   switch($tm->error){
      // handle it somehow here
   }
}
```

As for description for error codes, there's an [official page](https://github.com/stefangabos/Zebra_Image/)

### Make sure libgd is installed

http://libgd.github.io/

http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php

CentOS7

1. `yum install gd gd-devel php-gd`
2. restart apache

Comment: Hey check it out: http://www.classifiedtestbed.com/advertisements/2 it works now :D